# composition and partial composition of functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a nested vector of vectors, like `[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]]` and I want to increment the values of each sub-vector, then find the max of each sub-vector. The formulation I'm using is:

```
(map (comp (partial apply max) (partial map inc)) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@xsc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26547373/1562315), but respecting the order of operations ...

```
(map #(->> % (map inc) (apply max)) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])
;(4 7 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you can combine `max`/`inc` and save one call to `map`:

```
(map (comp inc #(apply max %)) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])
;; => (4 7 10)
```

But that's only a marginal improvement and actually inverts the order of operations. Might be more readable, though.

Comment: ... or `(map #(->> %, (apply max), inc) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])`

Comment: Inverting the order of operations is an issue sadly - this is a simplified version of the problem, where the inc operation might vary depending on the context. I over-simplified it, sorry! In practice I'm doing a `(partial map :keyword)` to access the required value first, rather than a straight `inc`

Comment: @OliverMooney ... Then `(map #(->> % (map inc) (apply max)) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])`

Comment: @Thumbnail Thanks, that looks good, and I like how the order of operations matches the order in the code now too. There seems to be some interesting overlaps between ->>/->, partial and comp that I need to dig into. Do you want to put this as a separate answer?